# Replacement for an AC Transformer

Tags: ac, transformer

I have a model train set that have an AC transformer. The transformer looks like one of those typical adapters where there is a wire connected to the outlet. Then you have a big black box that weights a ton and then a wire that comes out witha plug that I connect to the train set. The specs read:

Model No: A380104148
Input: 120 V AC 60 Hz 80W
Output: 10 V AC 3200 mA

OK I am looking in the internet for AC transformers but I cannot find any aside from transformers that have no housing (https://www.alliedelec.com/edwards-signaling-590/70429683/). Are there any kind of plug-in adapters with the specs to replace mine. Maybe I am using the incorrect search terms. I have looked for AC adapters, AC transformers without success.

Comment: maybe go to the model train shop.

Comment: A380104148 has several listings on Ebay

Comment: My question was a bit convoluted. In fact my question was regarding more the specs. I called a train shop but they told me that this was a "special transformer". I didnt buy this. It have a special controller but the transformer seems like an AC transformer to me. I think @Tony EE rocketscientist provided the answer I was looking for.

Comment: either you need the 32VA transformer or a somethig larger  "80W"  implies at-least 80VA

Answer (score 1):

[D-K has a search engine with some results](https://www.digikey.com/products/en/transformers/power-transformers/164?k=&pkeyword=&sv=0&pv1989=0&pv1617=146&pv1617=32&pv1617=11&pv1617=51&pv1617=28&pv1617=87&pv1617=78&pv1617=5&pv1617=123&pv1617=202&pv1617=105&pv1617=166&pv1617=168&pv588=1291&pv588=1202&pv588=1118&pv588=1195&pv588=1342&pv588=1103&pv588=1184&pv588=1178&pv588=1139&pv588=1319&pv588=1250&pv588=1112&pv588=1333&pv588=1275&pv588=1109&pv588=1266&pv588=1619&pv588=1341&pv588=1231&pv588=1335&pv588=1545&pv588=1225&pv588=1254&pv588=1300&pv588=1197&pv588=1228&pv588=1216&pv588=1152&pv588=1546&pv588=1267&pv588=1157&pv588=1256&pv588=1105&pv588=1115&pv588=1144&pv588=1395&pv588=1269&pv588=1205&pv588=1620&pv588=1243&pv588=1149&sf=1&FV=ffe000a4&quantity=&ColumnSort=0&page=1&pageSize=25)

Choose Vin 120V  Vout 10V

VA>=10V*3.2A  = 32VA

to 50VA or whatever.

So this has a separate speed controller?

Comment: Yes this have a separate controller that controls speed; direction and even have sound effects. https://www.ebay.com/itm/VTG-New-Bright-The-Holiday-Express-Animated-Train-Set-No-387-Santa-Xmas-Electric-/202509643075?oid=202097424933 I guess my whole question was regarding the specs and you have explained how to find one with the correct VA rating.